# Get all values from Firebase Database without knowing some child names

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm trying to get some child `values` without knowing the parent-child `keys` because they are UUID's generated by the user or firebase.

My firebase structure is like so:

```
{
  AllUsers: {

      76f4bd92-1fcd-4b4d-86c5-66b7e2822def: { // uuid generated by user

            Users Username: {

                -LCdF2QJ5c46lRnndtmY: { // uuid generated by firebase
                    count: 1,
                    dateTime: 1526479204163,
                    name: "picture1",
                    url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
                },
                -LCdF2QJ5c46lRnndtmQ: {
                    count: 2,
                    dateTime: 1526479204163,
                    name: "picture2",
                    url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
                }
            }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the users generated `uuid` and `usernames`, and the `url` of their first image when sorted by `count`, so that I can save them to a structure like so:

```
class GalleryFolderView {
  String uuid;
  String name;
  String firstImageUrl;

  GalleryFolderView(this.uuid, this.name, this.firstImageUrl);
}
```

I have gotten this far with my code but can't get any deeper into the structure:

```
  reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("AllUsers");
  reference.onValue.listen((Event event) {
    var key = event.snapshot.value.keys.toString();
    print(key); => // prints out (76f4bd92-1fcd-4b4d-86c5-66b7e2822def) why the brackets? 
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
 reference.onValue.listen((Event event) {
    var value = event.snapshot.value;
    var uuids = value.keys;
    for(var uuid in uuids) {
      var userNames = value[uuid].keys;
      for(var userName in userNames) {
        var images = value[uuid][userName].values;
        var image = images.firstWhere((img) => img[count]== 1);
        print('uuid: $uuid, userName: $userName, url: $image);
      }
    } 
  });
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you. How would i find the lowest `img[count]` if the lowest number could be anything?

Comment: `import 'dart:math' as math;` `var lowestId = images.map((img) => img[count]).reduce((a, b) => math.min(a, b));` `var image = images.firstWhere((img) => img[count]== lowestId);

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting an error on `math.min` saying `Could not infer type parameter T. Tried to infer Dynamic for T which doesnt work` the mesage goes on for longer

Comment: Please try `math.min<int>(a, b)`